# Is this a good way to get the average of the input numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables

I'm writing a function to return the mean of the user's comma-separated input.

```
def get_average () :
    grades = input()
    grades = grades.split(",")
    grades = [int(x) for x in grades]
    average = (sum(grades))/(len(grades))
    return round(average, 2)
```

Is this a good way to do so? What about the fact that I redefined the `grades` variable twice?  Is there a more practical way to do it?

Comment: This code is fine

Answer (score 1):

Reusing `grades` just makes the program harder to read, as `grades` now means three different, semantically incompatible things.  Try using more descriptive names, then combining intermediate steps.  For instance:

```
input_line = input("Please enter the grades, separated by commas")
grades = [int(x) for x in input_line.split(',')]
```

Other than the superfluous outer parentheses in the mean computation, you're doing fine so far.

Answer (score 1):

You could write it a bit more elegant, but nothing is wrong with redefining `grades` in these three consecutive lines. It works, and as it is so close together it won't create confusion.

Here would be my go for a more elegant solution using python's statistics module from the standard lib:

```
import statistics

def get_average():
    user_input = input('Please enter integer numbers separated by commas: ')
    average = statistics.mean(map(int, user_input.split(',')))
    return round(average, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you, it definitely helps to learn quite a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is fine, to be more pythonic you can chain calls like:

```
grades = [int(x) for x in grades.split(',')]
```

without having to use a temporary assignment of `.split()`

You can do the same with the `round()` call:

```
return round(sum(grades) / len(grades), 2)
```

Comment: Thank you, that is going to simplify my function quite a lot.